# How to change an interface in Java and its consequences?

Tags: java, interface

What is the best practice for changing an interface in an application. If the interface has been implemented by many Java classes, what would be the best way to change it? Are you going to extend to a new class? Are you going to use any design pattern? or do you use delegation (I don't think there is any way using delegation)? Are you going to use deprecated annotation at all?

is this the best solution?

```
public interface interface1
{
}

public interface interface2 extends interface1
{
public void newMethod()
}
```

Comment: In Intellij IDEA there is a tool called Type Migration, as i remember just for such cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways that immediately spring to mind.

1. In your IDE, use a refactoring tool to change the interface.  The more advanced IDE's (Eclipse can - I don't know about others) can refactor any known implementations immediately.  This requires the affected projects to be open.
2. Your solution, `MyInterface2 extends MyInterface` is used extensively too, because it doesn't break existing implementors.

If your solution came up in a code audit or review, I wouldn't reject it - it's fine, IMHO.

Comment: You can also do a 'poor man's refactoring': change the interface, then wait for your IDE to flag up all the now-broken implementations. This also requires the implementing projects to be open. We've done this in the past where we needed to actually see (and review) all the implements of an interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you own the code, the best way to change an interface is to fix all references to it - rather than leave deprecated code around.

Comment: that's correct but the code might be big and you might not be able to change all the implementation at once

Answer (score 0):

If this method is not needed by all other classes implemented `interface1`, then I think by doing this you can avoid major code changes.

Then, next question, do we need this in `interface2` (or) just having in the required class is enough?

If you don't want to define this new method as `contract`, in other words no other classes need to implement, then I wouldn't even create a `interface2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use design patterns. 
Abstract Factory or Bridge pattern can be used

Comment: Can you provide the sample code for this solution? I don't think it will be a good idea to use Abstract Factory or Bridge pattern, they have overheads for this simple solution, don't they?